# CSS element rotation

Tags: html, css, rotation, margin

I am a beginner

I have rotated a div 90 degrees with dynamic text content (a side bar) which is fine,
but when I increase the text it moves right,this is my problem it needs to stay on a fixed position on the left.
Here's my code:

```
<div id="aside"> 
    <a href="">
        <span id="up-image"></span>
        <span id="dragg">zi dragg</span>
        <span id="down-image"></span>   
    </a>    
</div>
```

..and for the rotation i have used:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.93969262, M12=0.34202014, M21=-0.34202014, M22=0.93969262,sizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE6-8 */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

I have set a fixed position to the "aside" with top and left and negative margin.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're talking about. "increase the text in moves right"?

Comment: Provide us a jsfiddle if possible

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is with the property [`Transform Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) wich defines:

> the origin for transformations of an element

And the default value is `50% 50%` then if you increase the size of your element in a dynamic way the origin point of the rotation change and of course "moves to the right" since the point is 50% of the actual size.

You can define it to be more flexible with dynamic size, try this:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
```

<sub>Don't forget to include all vendor prefixes</sub>

Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/qgG8b/.